# Why filesize of uploaded images become 0B when uploading it from AWS sdk(PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I tried with multiple changes but nothing worked for me. The same code works fine when tried in the test environment but when copying to into real code with required changes all uploaded files after upload become 0B.

```
//file upload
$filePath = $id.rand(0000,9999).$_FILES["file"]["name"].".jpg";


//Put on S3
  // Put on S3
$s3->putObject(
  array(
    'Bucket'=>$bucketName,
    'Key' =>  $filePath,
    'sourceFile' => fopen($filePath, 'w'),
    'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD',
    'ACL'    => 'public-read'
  )
);
```

Comment: Check AWS S3 CDN documentation OR the bucket permissions may help you find any clues.

Comment: Does `$filePath` exist? Either you removed a bunch of code between the first two lines and everything else or the file doesn't exist.

Comment: yes $filePath exist..see the first line. When s3 code removed file saved in the database perfectly but when these code includes filesize getting 0B and I recheck many times nothing is miss. Many advice this problem with latest version of aws-sdk revert to previous version and it will work but in my case it didn't